# Jenkins multi branch project and Github webhooks

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Looks like I'm missing something.

I set up multibrunch jon in Jenkins with SCM like git@github.someorg.com/repo.git It scanned all current branches.

Then I set up web hook in Github with URL http://jenkins.someorg.com/github-webhook/ for all events.

Github shows that event has been successfully sent. 
Jenkins log shows that events has bees received.

```
Received PUSH for https://github.someorg.com/repo from IP ⇒ http://jenkins.someorg.com/github-webhook/
```

But nothing happens on the Jenkins job itself...

Comment: Found solution. I was using Git repo. But when I switched to Github with API key, everything worked

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Double-check "[Setting up a GitHub webhook in Jenkins](https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/setting-up-a-github-webhook-in-jenkins/)"

You need to make sure your Build Trigger is set to  “Build when a change is pushed to GitHub”, with of course a GitHub repo url ;)

[image: https://i1.wp.com/thepracticalsysadmin.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/jenkins4.jpg?resize=300%2C200&ssl=1]

And Jenkins should have an SSH key already associated with the desired GitHub project.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. I was using Git repo. But when I switched to Github with API key, everything worked

Comment: would you provide more details?